# upgrade pandas to pandas-0.12.0 on Windows | Error message: 'Unable to find vcvarall.bat'

Tags: python, windows, pandas

I want to upgrade pandas to pandas-0.12.0 on Windows7. I installed MinGW first. But I still get the error message 'Unable to find vcvarall.bat'

Any suggestions?

Comment: is there a reason why you are not using he pre compiled binaries on pypi?

Answer (score -1):

Note that you do not need MinGW to run pandas, it's a optional.
But if you like to use it than check this page:
http://wiki.cython.org/InstallingOnWindows

Comment: @Jeff I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Use windows binary to update your pandas https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/p/pandas/pandas-0.12.0.win-amd64-py2.7.exe

Comment: @user1374969 Unless you are actually developing pandas code itself on windows, you don't need to compile on windows (and even then its not recommended!). Use the pre-compiled binaries (link is above) to install via  windows-installer.

Comment: @Jeff Yes, I tried that first and it gave me this message when I started a new session and imported pandas. That's probably not helpful information to you, I know. Something went screwy here.

Comment: Do not recommend installing from source for most users. Please use the binary installers from PyPI